# Antonym of the word Coward in the given sentence

Tags: word-request, antonyms

I found this question tricky. What would be the antonym of the word coward in this sentence "I heard that the new student in our class is a coward"

Comment: Can you demonstrate some dictionary use here.  A thesaurus will list related words.  Note that "coward" is a noun, and nouns don't always have antonyms.  (What is the opposite of "apple"?)  A sentence carrying opposite meaning might not use a noun.  Would you accept an answer with a sentence with opposite meaning, but no antonym for "coward"

Comment: No, the sentence can't be modified

Comment: You haven't told us *why* the new student might be considered a ***coward***. The only antonym *noun* that comes to mind is ***hero***, but that wouldn't necessarily fit your context. You might be better switching to an *adjective*, as in *I heard he's **brave, bold, courageous***. But actually, it might be the "coward" is simply someone who doesn't want to admit to having done something they shouldn't have done, in which context the "best fit" antonym might be something like ***forthcoming***.

Comment: Can you demonstrate some dictionary use here. A thesaurus will list related words.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't easy to state a direct antonym for 'coward'. However, you could reason this way - a 'coward' is someone who displays *cowardice*. It is easier to find synonyms and antonyms of a 'quality', and you will find that *bravery* is a primary choice. One word for a person who shows bravery is a '*braveheart*'.

Depending on the context, you might also consider the word 'hero', but that would suggest they have done something *heroic*, which may certainly include a display of bravery but maybe other qualities too. Bravery can just be a display of inner strength, rather than an outwardly, benevolent act. For example, you might call a person who endured pain "brave", but not necessarily a "hero".

Note that most consider 'bravery' to be a willingness to act *despite* fear, or *in the face of fear*, whereas 'cowardice' means giving in to fear. These two different responses to the same emotion are sometimes referred to as "fight or flight".

Remember also that it is often a matter of opinion or perspective when someone is branded a 'coward'. For example, someone may be called a 'coward' for choosing not to fight a battle, yet that individual's reason for not fighting might be a moral one, so from their perspective, they may be showing moral strength by their action (or inaction).

Comment: Thank you very much